# How to use an Oracle Associative Array in a SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, associative-array, odp.net

ODP.Net exposes the ability to pass Associative Arrays as params into an Oracle stored procedure from C#.  Its a nice feature unless you are trying to use the data contained within that associative array in a sql query.

The reason for this is that it requires a context switch - SQL statements require SQL types and an associative array passed into PL/SQL like this is actually defined as a PL/SQL type.  I believe any types defined within a PL/SQL package/procedure/function are PL/SQL types while a type created outside these objects is a SQL type (if you can provide more clarity on that, please do but its not the goal of this question).

So, the question is, what are the methods you would use to convert the PL/SQL associative array param into something that within the procedure can be used in a sql statement like this:

```
OPEN refCursor FOR
SELECT T.*
FROM   SOME_TABLE T,
       ( SELECT COLUMN_VALUE V
         FROM   TABLE( associativeArray )
       ) T2
WHERE  T.NAME = T2.V;
```

For the purposes of this example, the "associativeArray" is a simple table of varchar2(200) indexed by PLS_INTEGER.  In C#, the associativeArry param is populated with a string[].

**Feel free to discuss other ways of doing this besides using an associative array but know ahead of time those solutions will not be accepted.  Still, I'm interested in seeing other options.**

Comment: See here for a similar problem + similar solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625649/oracle-parameters-with-in-statement/1655743#1655743

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would create a database type like this:

```
create type v2t as table of varchar2(30);
/
```

And then in the procedure:

```
FOR i IN 1..associativeArray.COUNT LOOP
    databaseArray.extend(1);
    databaseArray(i) := associativeArray(i);
END LOOP;

OPEN refCursor FOR
SELECT T.*
FROM   SOME_TABLE T,
       ( SELECT COLUMN_VALUE V
         FROM   TABLE( databaseArray )
       ) T2
WHERE  T.NAME = T2.V;
```

(where databaseArray is declared to be of type v2t.)

Comment: Its amazing how many examples there are of using Associative arrays in loops to run inserts and such but no that discuss or provide examples for side-stepping the context switch issue.  Hopefully this will be helpful to others as well.

Comment: This is not creating an associative array - it is creating a collection. Also note: `asscoiativeArray.FIRST` may not be `1` and `associativeArray.COUNT` and `associativeArray.LAST` may not be equal (especially if the associative array is sparse).

Comment: @MT0 I didn't say it was "how to create an associative array", I was explaining how I would solve the problem of using data in SQL that is currently in an associative array - by moving it to a collection. I have assumed the associative array is not sparse it's true - if not then different code would be needed clearly!

Comment: @TonyAndrews If the associative array is a non-sparse 1-indexed array then this is almost always an indicator that you did not need an associative array in the first place and would be better off to have started with a collection (in which case this question becomes academic).

Comment: However, the use of associative arrays might be due to a limitation of ODP.Net as the [`OracleCollectionType` enumeration](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/win.102/b14307/OracleCollectionTypeEnumeration.htm) only lists `PLSQLAssociativeArray` and does not appear to support other (more appropriate) collection types.

Comment: Yes that would seem to be the case, and it seems unlikely they would be perverse enough to send a sparse array in.  Hence OP's acceptance of this answer (about 8 years ago :-))

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use associative arrays in the SQL scope - they are only usable in the PL/SQL scope.

One method is to map the associative array to a collection (which can be used in the SQL scope if the collection type has been defined in the SQL scope and not the PL/SQL scope).

**SQL**:

```
CREATE TYPE VARCHAR2_200_Array_Type AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(200);
/
```

**PL/SQL**

```
DECLARE
  TYPE associativeArrayType IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(200) INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
  i                PLS_INTEGER;
  associativeArray associativeArrayType;
  array            VARCHAR2_200_Array_Type;
  cur              SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
  -- Sample data in the (sparse) associative array
  associativeArray(-2) := 'Test 1';
  associativeArray(0)  := 'Test 2';
  associativeArray(7)  := 'Test 3';

  -- Initialise the collection
  array := VARCHAR2_200_Array_Type();

  -- Loop through the associative array
  i := associativeArray.FIRST;
  WHILE i IS NOT NULL LOOP
    array.EXTEND(1);
    array(array.COUNT) := associativeArray(i);
    i := associativeArray.NEXT(i);
  END LOOP;

  -- Use the collection in a query
  OPEN cur FOR
    SELECT *
    FROM   your_table
    WHERE  your_column MEMBER OF array;
END;
/
```