# Passing and using a List<string> as Oracle Binding Parameter

Tags: c#, oracle, arraylist, query-string

I have a query ending with :

```
AND U2.USER_ID IN (:ToUserIDs)
```

My ToUserIDs is List<string> being created from entries in a TextBox.:

```
ToUserIDs = new List<string>(ToUserIDsTextBox.Text.Split(new string[] { "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
```

My OracleParameter is set up as follow:

```
OracleParameter oracleParameter3 = oracleDataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(":ToUserIDs", OracleDbType.NVarchar2);
oracleParameter3.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
oracleParameter3.CollectionType = OracleCollectionType.PLSQLAssociativeArray;
oracleParameter3.Value = (List<string>)args["ToUserIDs"];
```

Here I am running into deep water as I am not sure who to handle Lists/Arrays in an OracleParameter.

I am getting this error:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]'
> to type 'System.String[]

Comment: An associative array is a PL/SQL data type and cannot be used in an SQL context so even if you fix the C# errors casting between data types, I'm not sure you can then fix the underlying issue with passing a list of strings. One method may be to pass it to a procedure (or function) which converts the associative array to a non-associative collection and then uses that in a query.

Answer (score 0):

This wont work. The IN in clause only supports:

- fixed length of scalars, like:

  ```
  AND U2.USER_ID IN (:P1, :P2, :P3)
  ```
- a subquery

  ```
  AND U2.USER_ID IN (select x from y)
  ```

You can rewrite your query using `TABLE` cast keyword

```
   AND U2.USER_ID IN (select * from TABLE(:P1))
```

Where P1 is parameter of type: array of varhar2

Answer (score 0):

Used a post by @saminpa ([Oracle Parameters with IN statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625649/oracle-parameters-with-in-statement/56245878#56245878)) as solution.

```
AND         U2.USER_ID      IN (SELECT IDS.ToUserID FROM XMLTABLE('/ToUserIDs/ToUserID' PASSING XMLTYPE (:ToUserIDsElement) COLUMNS ToUserID VARCHAR(100) PATH '/ToUserID/.') IDS)
```